# Sawtooth waveform using DAC

Tags: dac, waveform

I am trying to create a sawtooth waveform using microcontroller/counter and DAC. Instead of getting a nice smooth ramp, I am getting a ramp but with impulses and other noise. I am using [AD7533](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7533.pdf) DAC and [AD8055](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8055_8056.pdf) Op Amp. The 10 bit input comes from a microcontroller. I am interfacing the DAC using figure11 from dac's datasheet:

[image]

Considering the note under the drawing, I decided to omit R1 and R2 from the circuit and made it the following way:

[image]

When I measure the signal at the negative terminal of the OpAmp, I get this reading:

[image]

which is not that attractive. Changing Vref does not make much difference. At Vref=5V the signal on the negative OpAmp input looks like this:

[image]

When I measure the signal on the OpAmp output pin, it looks like saturated:

[image]

So, two questions:

1. Am I missing some trivial components? Why the signal looks so bad?
2. Why OpAmp gets saturated if I do not do any gain? Moreover, the signal is withing 0-3V range and the power on the OpAmp is 5V.

**EDIT:**
So, I considered suggestions from the comments (shorted R2 and added negative rail to OpAmp power) and there I am getting this waveform:

[image]

It still looks very noisy and when I zoomed it in, the ramp also looks to float up and down:

[image]

Theoretically, since my range is about 3.3V peak to peak, and given 10 bit resolution, the output signal should have resolution of 3.3mV. Whereas, the noise is as bad as 100mV.
Any practical approaches on how to fight this noise?

Also, my next stage is going to be [AD8531](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8531_8532_8534.pdf). I will use it as a high current G=1 buffer - the output from the AD8055 will be connected to +in of the AD8531. Do I need to place the load resistor to ground between the two amps, or connect the output to the input directly?

Comment: Does gnd and Vref also float up and down? Where is your ground connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Considering the note under the drawing, I decided to omit R1 and R2
>   from the circuit

R2 needs to be shorted to get this to work.

Op-amps don't work properly without feedback and that's what the line to pin 16 provides. There's probably a clue in the name of the pin if you look.

[image]

**EDIT** about power rails

I'm mentioning this because I think your AD8055 is powered from +5V and 0V - this will cause the problems listed below (if not using a negative rail) and I don't think the AD8055 is rated to run below a supply rail of +/-4V. Looking at your picture of the output, it appears to be bottoming out at somewhat above +500mV and rather similar to what the implied lowest output level would be on this device in the data sheet.

Just in case your supply regime is wrong, this is how it should look (different chip but same principle): -

[image]

Note the negative and positive rails on the op-amp because Iout is positive for a positive reference and for the Iout pin to be held at virtual earth, the op-amp's output must fall below 0V. Here's probably a more explicit example: -

[image]

Note that for a Vref voltage of (say) +2.5V, maximum output will be virtually -2.5V with lower values heading to 0V. At no time will the output be positive unless you use a voltage reference that is negative. This is a multiplying DAC configuration and inversion is inherent.

Comment: Thank you. I shorted the R2 and provided +/-5V for opAmp supply voltage and now it's all good. However, I really want to avoid having negative rail. Do you have any suggestions how to modify the circuit to be within 0-5V range? I can do 0-12V on the OpAmp power.

Comment: @Naz, what about a negative voltage reference? If not then look for a DAC that is voltage output type not current output type.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Andy's answer, the reason your op-amp is slamming between 0 and Vdd is because there is no feedback. It's acting like a comparator. If V+ > V-, output=1. If V+ < V-, output = 0. With feedback, the op-amp will be able to steady in on some value that holds V- at V+.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andy's correct reply, I recognize the spikes as digital noise getting into the analog, from excessive gain from missing feedback, R2.

This can either be from DAC ground current or crosstalk to the analog Vref.   Notice how the biggest spike is mid scale where ...011111 switches to ...100000.  Lack of isolated digital and analog ground and Vref coupling will produce thus. Although, I have never seen it this bad.

Look at beefing up grounds, shielding and isolating the DAC input current from the analog section. If it still looks bad, call supplier for tech support. I had one like this but only a few bits of spikes from Burr Brown in the old hybrid packages, from Vref noise.

Connecting R2 should reduce the impedance and gain, both correcting most of the problems. The residual noise can be inspected from above comments.

Comment: How do I isolate digital and analog grounds? Both lines use the same power supply.

Comment: This takes some imagination but current loops have conductive and inductive voltage drops. Many methods. When impedance is low, the noise is low. So large ground planes is 1 way. another is 2 large planes joined by short inductive track at common point, another is differential logic, (not for here) another is differential analog (not here)   Give thought to impulse currents from logic edge driving capacitance and make sure none of mV drop contributes to analog voltage.  Same for Power glitches

Comment: Is it OK to connect microcontroller output directly to the DAC Digital input? Do I need pulldown resistors? anything else?

Comment: Yes but what is your ground impedance? This demands layout info , analysis, how small are spikes after R2 is added

Comment: If wide tracks used in long ground paths , consider braid. Show layout in photo.  Consider differential OA with high CMMR on output.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only prototyping it on a DIP pcb board - that's the layout info. Do you mean to use diff. op amp instead of AD8055? Do you think [AD8132](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8132.pdf) would work?

Comment: Do you know how to make a balanced differential output DAC and input to OA in diff mode? Poor ground ... Very inductive

Comment: No, I do not know. It does not seem to be the best solution, right? But what should I do to minimize the noise and floating of the output signal from the dac?

Comment: Start by eliminating measurement error. Measure ground , then VRef noise. Is it zero?

Comment: Your probe gnd shud be < 5cm on pin 3 of DAC or use 2 probes 1-2 mode

Comment: When I put the probe on Vref - it does not seem to float. But the dac ouput floats like on water.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13962/discussion-between-naz-and-joe)

Comment: You must have Out 1&2 reversed. Out1 is the only one that floats , which is grounded and that is only for all 1's input.

Comment: The Op Amp in use must be able to accept inputs to ground.  Since Out1 is gnd and for all1's Out2 switches are open but is connected via Rf to OA out which will be a unity gain mode where output matches input = 0V. Nothing is floating on the OA inputs.

Comment: My ground is a common ground for everything: power supply, DAC, OpAmp, oscilloscope. When I put the probe on Vref - it does not seem to float. I use bypass and decoupling caps everywhere. I connected everything like suggested in the datasheet: Out2 to GND and Out1 to -in of the opAmp, they are not reversed.

Comment: Re-read my comments, look at DAC internal schematic, nothing should be floating. Measure impedance adding 1M pullup to Vref and see if it changes DC level

Comment: What I mean by floating is flactuation of the DAC output: instead of solid ramp, it looks wavy.

Comment: Does pattern change with sawtooth rate? If not the DAC input is affecting Vref to ground difference.  Use twin probes in difference mode to find your layout issue. Both probes on same signal should read null when done right. Also increase Vref and Vdd to specs.if that fails, change chip

Comment: I increased the rate by 3. Well, the wave is there, but slower. So, I guess, the pattern did not change. The dac is connected 0,+5V, and my Vref is about -2V and comes from different power supply.

Comment: I noticed that decreases and increases periodically, just like in-phase and out-of-phase. In other words, the wave slowly increases in magnitude, then decreases, and disappears. Then, it seems to go the other direction.

Comment: It seems you have Common mode interference from a source unknown. ac E field.  Improve  your grounds. With a ground plane shield

Comment: I think I managed to upload the video [here](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2sb60wj%3E&s=8#.U1AaevldXHU)

Comment: Yup . Adjust sawtooth near line frequency to confirm CM line noise issue then add gnd shield.  Add capacitance to feedback in opamp to integrate the glitches . Compare results with spec for glitch volt-nanosec. Make sure Vref has good low ESR film cap near DAC chip. Since there is switched capacitance inside, Vref must be low impedance at RF

Comment: I did not do anything, but the fluctuations seem to disappear. I will have to wait and see maybe something will turn on and produce this wavy pattern. So far, I am left with the voltage spikes and general +/-3mV noise. Any suggestions on how to reduce it? Also, I will drive the electomagnetic coil with this sawtooth wave. Any necessary protection for the opAmp? I use [AD8531](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8531_8532_8534.pdf) and yes, I use 15pF cap in place of C1